# Experiencing microstutters in all games after changing to RTX 2070 video card

Tags: cpu, performance, gpu, lag

So about 2 weeks ago I bought an RTX 2070, and ever since I've had microstutters in all games I play. They are of different severity, depending on the game. I'm looking for a way to fix that.

First of all, here is my system:
Windows 10 64 bit build 17134
Gigabyte Z77X-UD5H
Intel I7 3770k @4.4 GHZ
16GB of 1333 mhz DDR3 RAM
RTX 2070
120 GB SSD (Windows system drive)
2TB 7200rpm HDD (all games are on here)
1080p 60HZ BenQ monitor

They are very frequent in Rocket League, but also very short, so they don't impact me much.
In League of Legends they are almost unnoticeable, and rare.
In Black Ops 4 they make the game unplayable. Every other minute the screen freezes up. Never more than a second or so, but that's more than enough in that game.

I have tried different SATA ports for my SSD and HDD
I have used DDU and done a clean install of the newest GPU drivers.
I have tried just about every setting in the NVDIA settings.
I have removed my PCI WLAN card.

Some things have helped a little bit:
Putting my GPU in a PCIE x8 slot (was in x16) and also putting my sound card in a PCIE x1 slot (was in x4). In latencymon this removed the issues with ndis.sys latency, but didn't help the stutters.

Turning off all C-states, and all other CPU power saving options in the bios. This was the only thing that made a noticeable difference. The microstutters only start after a few minutes of game play now, and they seem to be less severe in BO4, though they are unchanged in all other games.

Screenshot of Latencymon: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdOeC.jpg
Screenshot of drivers sorted by DPC count:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/qahPK.jpg
Screenshot of drivers sorted by ISR count: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ljKr.jpg
Screenshot of drivers sorted by execution time:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOURr.jpg
Screenshot of the CPU tab of latencymon:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQJA4.jpg
And the summary:  https://pastebin.com/s8xTKgdY

I also created a CPU.etl file, but that one is from yesterday, before I re-seated my GPU. I'll add it anyways.  I forgot how to make it (found the instructions on one of the many forum posts that I searched through in the past few days and have since not found it again), so if someone can tell me how, I'll make an updated one.  Here it is:   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bCrpI0QPFVPVAdC1QoPonwpCRE3z7eba

I also tried removing the OC from my CPU, but that changed nothing.

I know everything but my GPU is pretty old, and I'm gonna be replacing all of it in the next two months, but I would like to find out if the problem lies with the old hardware, some software, or even my new RTX 2070. If the problem is the GPU, I must return it, and soon, since I can only return it for two more days.

I have found many people with similar problems, but most of them also have audio stutters. In my case I don't notice audio stutters (maybe because the microstutters are too short to notice), and I don't suffer from "weird popping noises".

However, I did find a few people with the exact issues as me. One example is this thread:  https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/1082625/rtx-2070-stuttering-across-the-board-/
Note the example in the first comment, that's what the most severe stutters looked like in my case, before I re-seated my GPU. Now they are a little shorter than that.

If there is any more information you need to help me I'm happy to provide it.

EDIT: I have noticed, during, and shortly after the more severe stutters, the GPU usage would drop to around 60% (from close to 100%).

EDIT: I spent a couple of hours doing what was suggested to me by K7AAY in [this answer.](https://superuser.com/a/1382410/609164) On default there were frequent stutters, some severe ones. After deactivating onboard audio (using xonar dgx 5.1) the stutters started a little later, but were then as frequent as before. Deactivating c1e, c3/c6: just as before, but didn't notice any severe ones. Deactivating eist: stutters seemed less frequent. Deactivating cpu pll overload and activating hyper-threading: some severe stutters, otherwise just as before. Now the only changes left would be re-applying the OC.

Comment: Do you use MSI After Burner by chance?

Comment: Have you ruled out CPU overheating as a cause? A faster GPU can put more pressure on the CPU and it's also possible that while swapping the GPU, you inadvertently caused the CPU to mate poorly with its heatsink.

Comment: I do use MSI Afterburner. But the problems persist when I turn it off or even uninstall it.

And my CPU never goes beyond 85 degrees even during stresstests, so overheating should not be the issue.

Comment: What resolution are you running games at?

The only thing I can think of is it could be your mechanical hard drive. I had a bad hard drive that had random latency spikes that would cause terrible stutters in games like GTA 5. Try moving a game to your SSD. I doubt that is the issue, but it's worth a shot. With a much more powerful GPU you are likely running at higher settings and are thus loading much larger and many more textures into vram than you were before, which puts a much larger load on your HDD than your old GPU did.

Answer (score 1):

The microstuddering is very likely due to a CPU bottleneck based on the screencaps and admissions you made here. Keep an eye on CPU usage in your next session, if your CPU is pinned near or at 100% a majority of the time that's probably it. If you have a friend that has a rig with a nicer CPU, slot your GPU in there and test it out to rule out defects. The data you posted also points out that power settings may help to throttle the CPU so review those too, I wouldn't be surprised if you already have it at Max Performance, but wouldn't hurt to check.

I'd also like to point out that you may have an I/O bottleneck with your storage setup, OS and games should be on the SSD, and bulk data on the spinners. When you go to upgrade consider getting a much larger SSD that should also help a little.

Comment: It is HIGHLY unlikely that an overclocked 3770k@4.4GHz is causing a CPU bottleneck for a game like Rocket League...

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you reboot, go into the BIOS/Setup mode with [**Del**], and reset to the Default Optimized Settings with [**F7**], then immediately save those settings with [**F10**] ?

Test, and then, one item at a time, introduce any BIOS adjustments, saving and then testing to see if it's really an improvement. A review of your [motherboard manual](http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-z77x-ud5h_e.pdf) may be helpful, as is watching the mobo, RAM, and CPU temps with [Open Hardware Monitor](https://openhardwaremonitor.org/).

Comment: I spent a couple of hours doing this.   
On default there were frequent stutters, some severe ones.  
After deactivating onboard audio (using xonar dgx 5.1) the stutters started a little later, but were then as frequent as before.  
Deactivating c1e, c3/c6: just as before, but didn't notice any severe ones.  
Deactivating eist: stutters seemed less frequent.  
Deactivating cpu pll overload and activating hyper-threading:  some severe stutters, otherwise just as before.  
Now the only changes left would be re-applying the OC.

Comment: No I meant reapplying the overclock on my CPU. I have been running it at 4.4 GHZ, but by loading the default optimized settings the CPU clock was reverted to the stock of 3.5GHZ with boost up to 3.9GHZ.